# Windows 7: network not ready (blue circle is spinning)

Tags: networking, windows-7, readystate

On my Win7-PC the network takes up to 10 minutes until it's shown as ready (through network icon). The weird thing is that even in the meantime (blue circle is spinning) network activities like mail, internet and access to network shares are working.

How does Win7 decide that a network is ready?

The issue is that one of my installed apps which uses the IP stack (runs on localhost) doesn't work until the network is in ready-state. I found out that if I disable the Windows Management Instrumentation service the network state switches to ready immediately. However, this prevents a couple of other services from starting what could lead to a security issue. (To me it seems like my PC waits until it gets a GO from our network... but no evidence here)

Any hints?

Comment: Assigning static IP may fix this.

Comment: @accfews: I'm not allowed to use a fix IP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply this hotfix, sometimes it works:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2617858

When it happens to me I have to kill the process tree of two services:

- SMS Agent Host
- Winmgmt

(select the service, right click, select "go to process", right click on the process, select "end process tree"; if you cannot see the process remember to click the "show processes from all the users" button).
Finally delete the "c:\windows\system32\wbem\repository" folder as fast as possible.
The "repository" folder will be re-created and the network will start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

- Click on run dialog and type msconfig.
- In the pop up click on services.
- Then check/tick Hide Microsoft services.
- In the ensuing dialog uncheck/untick Nividia Network service.
- Finally click Apply. restart computer.

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling NVidia Network services stopped that for me.

While updating drivers etc. is good practice, it is usually just a wild goosechase.